# Как скрыть сплывающее title при наведении на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наводке на кнопку (ссылку) отображается ее title.
Вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
  <li>
     <a href="#" title="tab1" class="tab1">
    color
  </a>
   </li>
  </ul>

<div id="content">
  <div id="tab1">
    <ul id="buttonsContent">
    </ul>
```

Вот js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content > div").hide(); 
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current");
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); 

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content > div").hide(); 
        $("#tabs li").attr("id","");
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); 
        $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); 
    });

});
```

Так как скрыть сплывающее title при наведении на кнопку?Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?
И да, способ типа :

```
$("a").removeAttr("title");
```

Мне не подходит, так как скрывается сразу и контент в кнопке (если что, были созданы вкладки между которыми можно переключаться)

Comment: "так как скрывается сразу и контент в кнопке" - что это значит?

Comment: @Igor: меня больше смущает последняя строка `$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); ` Ужос о_0

Comment: @UModeL да, в ней-то и дело

Comment: А зачем вы используете title не по назначению? Для всяких своих данных есть data-атрибуты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> так как скрывается сразу и контент в кнопке

Потому что Вы решили привязать `id` содержимого к `title` ссылки:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn();
```

Используйте что-нибудь другое, например:

```
<a href="#" class="tab1" data-content="tab1">

$('#' + $(this).data('content')).fadeIn();
```